# Deobfuscating AS2 SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, deobfuscation

I lost my copy of the .fla version of my loader for my game. In order to continue building, I need to decompile it and start again. The problem is, I obfuscated it before I uploaded it onto the webserver. It is AS2 and I need to get the code and objects back. Could someone tell me how I can do this? Or link me to a free program?

If you want the SWF link, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is not generic ActionScript deobfuscation program as of today.

You may find deobfuscators created against specific obfuscators, like [this one](http://ijs.mtasa.com/files/swfdecrypt.cpp), but no generic tool, so you have to tell us the link of your SWF if you want to be helped.